# Failing to install PM2 using NPM package on Ansible 2.7 on Debian stretch

Tags: ansible

I am setting up a new server based on Debian 9 (stretch).

I have an Ansible playbook and when I try to install PM2 using the npm ansible module it fails and I am stuck with this for the last couple of days.

I am using ansible 2.7:

```
ansible 2.7.10
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 09:23:15) [Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)]
```

I tried to run the playbook with python 2 and 3 with no luck using `ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3` on the Inventory.

The weird thing is that if I ssh on the server and I run `npm install pm2 -g` it works perfectly fine.
Nvm also works fine on the server.

Before reaching this point the playbook installs several other packages:

- mongodb
- mysql-client
- redis
- various libraries
- etc

This is the extract from the playbook

```
tasks:
     ...

     - name: Install nvm
      sudo: no
      git: repo=https://github.com/creationix/nvm.git dest=~/.nvm version={{ NVM_VERSION }}
      tags: nvm

    - name: Source nvm in ~/.profile
      sudo: no
      lineinfile: >
        dest=~/.profile
        line="source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh"
        create=yes
      tags: nvm

    - name: Install versions
      shell: bash -lc "nvm install {{ item }}"
      register: output
      changed_when: "'already installed.' not in output.stderr"
      with_items: "{{ NVM_NODE_VERSIONS }}"
      sudo: no

    - name: Set default node version to {{ NVM_DEFAULT_NODE_VERSION }}
      command: sudo -iu admin nvm alias default {{ NVM_DEFAULT_NODE_VERSION }}
      tags: nvm

    - name: Install PM2 packages
      npm:
        executable: /home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v{{ NVM_DEFAULT_NODE_VERSION }}/bin/npm
        name: pm2
        global: yes
        state: present

....
```

The variables are defined as follow:

```
NVM_VERSION : "v0.33.0"
NVM_INSTALL_SCRIPT : "/home/admin/nvm_install.sh"
NVM_NODE_VERSIONS :
 - v10.15.3
 - v6.9.4
 - v8.10.0
 - v8.11.1
NVM_DEFAULT_NODE_VERSION: "10.15.3"
```

This is the error that I get:

```
{  
   "changed":false,
   "module_stderr":"Shared connection to 52.209.248.173 closed.\r\n",
   "module_stdout":"Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/home/admin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1554992741.43544-36230788449164/AnsiballZ_npm.py\", line 113, in <module>\r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File \"/home/admin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1554992741.43544-36230788449164/AnsiballZ_npm.py\", line 105, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r\n  File \"/home/admin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1554992741.43544-36230788449164/AnsiballZ_npm.py\", line 48, in invoke_module\r\n    imp.load_module('__main__', mod, module, MOD_DESC)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py\", line 234, in load_module\r\n    return load_source(name, filename, file)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py\", line 170, in load_source\r\n    module = _exec(spec, sys.modules[name])\r\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 626, in _exec\r\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 673, in exec_module\r\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_npm_payload_qlnd0iyr/__main__.py\", line 284, in <module>\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_npm_payload_qlnd0iyr/__main__.py\", line 261, in main\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_npm_payload_qlnd0iyr/__main__.py\", line 185, in list\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py\", line 319, in loads\r\n    return _default_decoder.decode(s)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py\", line 339, in decode\r\n    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py\", line 357, in raw_decode\r\n    raise JSONDecodeError(\"Expecting value\", s, err.value) from None\r\njson.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)\r\n",
   "msg":"MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
   "rc":1
}
```

Clearer error:

```
    MODULE FAILURE
    See stdout/stderr for the exact error

    MODULE_STDOUT:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/admin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1555331069.891913-182901060644739/AnsiballZ_npm.py", line 113, in <module>
        _ansiballz_main()
      File "/home/admin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1555331069.891913-182901060644739/AnsiballZ_npm.py", line 105, in _ansiballz_main
        invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
      File "/home/admin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1555331069.891913-182901060644739/AnsiballZ_npm.py", line 48, in invoke_module
        imp.load_module('__main__', mod, module, MOD_DESC)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
        return load_source(name, filename, file)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 170, in load_source
        module = _exec(spec, sys.modules[name])
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _exec
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 673, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/tmp/ansible_npm_payload_qvtn2qwx/__main__.py", line 284, in <module>
      File "/tmp/ansible_npm_payload_qvtn2qwx/__main__.py", line 261, in main
      File "/tmp/ansible_npm_payload_qvtn2qwx/__main__.py", line 185, in list
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
        raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

    MODULE_STDERR:

    OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
    debug1: Reading configuration data ~/.ssh/config
    debug1: ~/.ssh/config line 13: Applying options for *
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
    debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname <ip> is address
    debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
    debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
    debug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4
    debug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote
    debug3: mux_client_request_session: entering
    debug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering
    debug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 16293
    debug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent
    debug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe
    debug2: Received exit status from master 1
    Shared connection to <ip> closed.
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: executable: "/home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v{{ NVM_DEFAULT_NODE_VERSION }}/bin/npm" --> try within quotes

Comment: @error404 Thanks for the suggestion, I tried using quotes but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: can you please update the question with the full debug logs? Just wanted to understand on which tasks if the playbook failing

Comment: @error404 It is failing to execute: 'Install PM2 packages' the last task in the extract from the playbook.
What log do you want to see?
On the server nvm is installed correctly on the server, the default version is the expected one.

Comment: @kaiserbadl0 the reason I have asked for debug logs is because I can't co-relate the json error to the npm module. I have just executed the same module to install pm2 is get installed successfully but I have only one npm version I am installing multiple version meanwhile since the pm2 module has the default node version you can remove the executable keyword and give it a try

Comment: @error404 I installed a global version of node and everything worked fine. Thanks! If you write your comment as an answer  I'll accept it as the right solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installation of the global version of node has resolved the issue.